# Deserializing a field named "class" into a POJO using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, unmarshalling

This may look a dumb question, but I would like to deserialize a JSON object to a POJO `MyObject` with a field named `class`, which is a reserved keyword in Java... If possible, I'd like to keep `MyObject` Jackson/Json/Whatever-dependency free.

Do I need to add a (standard or Jackson-specific) Java annotation to my class field member to handle this? Or is there another work-around to have a "pure" java object? I can configure the Jackson object mapper if needed.

```
public class MyObject {
  public String field1;
  public String class; // FAIL
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since `class` is a reserved Java keyword, you cannot use it directly. If you simply want the generated JSON to have it, use `@JsonProperty` and set its `value` attribute.

```
public class MyObject {
    public String field1;

    @JsonProperty(value = "class")
    public String clazz; 
}
```